# Why must I delete the node_modules folder every time I pull from github

Tags: reactjs, git, github, node-modules

I know this may be a simple question to answer, but I am curious as to why I have to delete the node_modules folder everytime I pull from my github repo.
When I try and execute "npm start" after pulling from my repo, I receive the following error, and upon deleting the node_modules folder and executing "npm install" the problem is fixed for the time being.

```
sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT...
```

I have noticed that the folder shows up as part of the changes made while pushing as well (some 2,800 files).
Is this a scenario where I need to have the node_modules folder ignored (.gitignore) in order to stop this from happening?
Any explanation as to why this occurs would also be cool, just as a FYI for me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Don't check in `node_modules`, as general practice. NPM already uses `package-lock.json` for ensuring correct versioning. Having said that: if you *have* to delete `node_modules` each time, you need to fix your npm install, because you should not have to. Tell `npm` to fix itself using `npm cache verify` and if that doesn't fix it, your npm is properly broken enough to warrant a proper uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have followed said advice. I will also keep an eye if the issue persists and check npm. Thank you for the explanation and tip!! Stay safe and be well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add node_modules directory to .gitignore to not be pushed into repository and then delete it in there.
And node_modules should only be generated in your development environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This did the trick! Stay safe and be well!

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called `.gitignore` and paste the following code inside it (PS: you can use this file in all your projects, it contains almost all extensions and folders that you have to ignore when pushing your project to github):

```
# Numerous always-ignore extensions
*.diff
*.err
*.orig
*.log
*.rej
*.swo
*.swp
*.vi
*~
*.sass-cache
node_modules/
.tmp/
.vs

# OS or Editor folders
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
.cache
.project
.settings
.tmproj
*.esproj
nbproject
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
*.komodoproject
.komodotools
_notes
dwsync.xml
.sass-cache
.idea
```

Comment: Awesome!! I have added this to my .gitignore. Really appreciate the answer!! Stay safe and be well.